# Is there any way to have images adapted on it's own to a fixed resolution but shouldn't look odd?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I mean literally like there is anyway which would take a portrait image and set it to landscape sizes along with extra background like for filling so that the image will not look odd?

For instance this one is the original picture :

[image]

And now here it's distorted due to the fact that I set height & width to fixed values as : 
[image]

So is there any way which would turn this portrait picture into a landscap based picture with everything showing perfectly Okay not just by changing the resolutions just but I mean literally like will resize the picture in there and then add extra background to the picture so that the picture won't look odd?

Is it possible in HTML,CSS,PHP,JS?

Comment: Use image as `background-image`  with `background-size: cover`.

Comment: @JyotiPathania : Can you propose an example please with jsfiddle link?

Comment: hi.. wrap the images with a div and set the div elements max-height and max-width and make image height and width auto and set max-height and    max width to inherit from div

Comment: Not sure I'm getting the question correctly. Are you asking if there's a way to _add_ background to the photo that matches the current photo background when you change the size, or are you simply asking how to crop the photo?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Thanks for asking for the clarification, it seems that the answers which I have got seems to be okay for now but if you can post a better one that would be great.`background-size` should cover it.

Comment: You didn't really answer my question, though. But if any of the proposed answers works for you and background-size does the trick, you should accept the answer and use it.

Comment: You can use jquery Plugins: [imagefit](http://periplox.github.io/jquery.imagefit/), [imgLiquid](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid), [image-scale](https://github.com/gestixi/image-scale), [jquery-focuspoint](https://github.com/jonom/jquery-focuspoint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the other answers all suggest it, I'm going to go against the grain and say I don't think it's appropriate in this case to add CSS rules for each image since it looks like you're creating some sort of gallery. It's probably better to just use an `<img>` tag right in your HTML and that way you can dynamically generate the `src` without overly complicating things:

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.container img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' style="width:200px;height:200px">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNYR.png">
</div>
<div class='container' style="width:400px;height:200px">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNYR.png">
</div>
<div class='container' style="width:200px;height:400px">
  <span class="helper"></span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNYR.png">
</div>
```

Just make sure you don't have any whitespace between `.helper` and the `img`. It should work for any dimensions of container and image.

Comment: I like this answer and the trick with the helper! Have to say though: a dynamic `src` for the background can be easily achieved by setting everything in CSS except for the `background-image`, and set that using `style="..."` per element.

Comment: @Justastudent I thought of that as well, but it just seems like something that goes beyond "design" to me. Using an `img` also has the added benefits that users to easily right click and save it, it allows you to use an alt text which is better for SEO and screen readers, and it allows the page to be printed with those images still displayed.

Comment: All very true and good points, I was mostly remarking it for completeness :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will resize the image to make it fit without distortion of the ratios.

```css
.container {
width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNYR.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```

Comment: Can you center the image?

Comment: I updated the code to demonstrate the image is centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here

html

```
<div class="img-con">
<img src="http://www.mybligr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/most-beautiful-tiger-animals-pics-images-photos-pictures-6.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

css

```
.img-con
{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  max-height:300px;
  max-width:500px;
  padding:30px;
}

.img-con > img
{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  max-height:inherit;
  max-width:inherit;
}
```

here is the reference link [codepn link here](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/gRaXaL?editors=1100)

Comment: Please try to understand the question, The reference link has already a landscape image.